# Кириллица в mysql

Tags: mysql, кириллица, типы

Почему-то не могу найти ответа. Если, например, тип VARCHAR имеет максимальную длину 256 байтов, получается, максимальная длина фразы на русском языке будет в 2 раза меньше? И так для всех символьных типов mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> максимальная длина фразы на русском языке будет в 2 раза меньше?

Нет. Размер полей CHAR и VARCHAR измеряются в символах, а не в байтах.

> For example, utf8 characters require up to three bytes per character, so for a CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 column, the server must allocate 255 × 3 = 765 bytes per value.
>
> Storage for variable-length columns includes length bytes, which are assessed against the row size. For example, a VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 column takes two bytes to store the length of the value, so each value can take up to 767 bytes.

Подтверждающий пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0453/1

Comment: спасибо, а blob?

Comment: @Deus, BLOB и TEXT в байтах.